# Running two external 4k displays over thunderbolt to HDMI MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013).

Can I use two 3840 x 2160 external monitors over Thunderbolt 2 to HDMI connections if the laptop is in **closed-display mode**?

I would be perfectly happy with 30Hz refresh rate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can for the MacBook Pro (Retina, Late 2013) and later

If you use a 60Hz Multi Stream Transport display with the MacBook Pro with AMD Radeon R9 M370X graphics card only one additional Thunderbolt display is supported.

You can use 4K displays and Ultra HD TVs at the following resolutions and refresh rates via the built-in HDMI port of your Mac:

3840 x 2160 at 30Hz
4096 x 2160 at 24Hz (mirroring is not supported at this resolution)

Check out this page from Apple  https://support.apple.com/kb/sp690?locale=en_GB

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT206587

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: OP asked about the 2013, not 2015. 2013 is NVidia GT750M,  dual 2560x1600 max res. https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.3-15-dual-graphics-late-2013-retina-display-specs.html

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, that site is fantastic, I wasn't aware of it. If you add a short answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Updated with a link from Apple HDMI video output support for 1080p resolution at up to 60Hz
Support for 3840-by-2160 resolution at 30Hz
Support for 4096-by-2160 resolution at 24Hz